# Adding Namespace to parent element of XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml file of a company like this :

```
 <Employee>
 <name>Vikram</name>
 <department>Testing</department>
 <Employee>

package com.company;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee", namespace="Testing")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
//getters and setters
}
```

Am getting the Output as :

```
 <ns2:Employee xmlns="Testing">
 <name>Vikram</name>
 <department>Testing</department>
 <ns2:Employee>
```

but the output i want would be something like this :

```
 <Employee xmlns="Testing">
 <name>Vikram</name>
 <department>Testing</department>
 <Employee>
```

I would like to remove the ns2 prefix but i cannot go the `package-info` way. Is there any other way that JAXB does that for us without adding `ns2:` as a prefix on the root element.